# Help adding annotations to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, android-mapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to add annotations to NSMutableArray annToLoad so I can later perform [mapView addAnnotations:annToLoad];

It doesn't seem to be working, and when I log the array, I get a (null) value.

My code is below... thanks!!

```
// Loop Begins
DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Title"];  
ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SubTitle"];
ann.coordinate = coord;

[annToLoad addObject:ann];            
[ann release];
// Loop Ends

// Outside of Loop
[mapView addAnnotations:annToLoad];
```

Comment: Did you allocated memory to annToLoad array ?

Comment: Is the NSMutableArray alloc, init called above the loop?

Comment: I added a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *annToLoad;`... do I need the init/alloc even if it's declared in my header file?

Comment: Did you log the array just after the loop to see if the objects have been added in without a prob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alloc init the NSMutableArray and assign it to the property.  The property will retain what you set but you still need to alloc, init and assign.

You can either do it in the init of that class or above the loop - depending on the lifetime of the array you need.

Comment: Thanks bryanmac, how do I assign it to the property? Will it do it automatially when I do, annToLoad = [[NSArray init] alloc];`?

Comment: yes, you can assign like annToLoad = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];